# how to add grand child element in xml child elements section C# XML

Tags: c#, xml

I want to add a 3rd level grand child section into my XML.

Before:

```
<level1>
    <level2>
          <coolstuff name="name"/>
    </level2>
</level1>
```

After:

```
<level1>
    <level2>
          <stupidtags>
               <stupidtag name ="stupidname"/>
          <stupidtags>
          <coolstuff name="coolname"/>
    </level2>
</level1>
```

How should I add the `stupidtags` into the `level2` tag in C#?
I implement a little bit, how should i pass two level and let newNode append it that and it should above coolstuff tag?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileOfReportInXML);
XElement newNode= new XElement("stupidtags");
```

Comment: How is this question related to your C# tag? What exactly have you done so far and what is failing?

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I add a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xml linq (XDocument)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<level1>" +
                    "<level2>" +
                          "<coolstuff name=\"name\"/>" +
                    "</level2>" +
                "</level1>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XElement level2 = doc.Descendants("level2").FirstOrDefault();

            level2.Add(new XElement("stupidtags", new object[] {
                    new XElement("stupidtag", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("name", "stupidname")
                })
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below sample code should demonstrate how to add a node to an existing XML in a given location

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("file.xml");               // fetch the existing XML

// create the grand child node to be inserted
var node = xml.CreateElement("level3");
node.SetAttribute("attrname", "attrvalue");
var level2Node = xml.SelectSingleNode("level1/level2"); // Use XPath to find the location of insertion

level2Node.PrependChild(node);      // Insert the Node in the grand child position

xml.Save("out.xml");                // store the new xml in a new file for demo
```

Below is the content of `file.xml` and `out.xml`

```xml
D:\tmp>type file.xml 
<level1>
    <level2>
          <coolstuff name="name"/>
    </level2>
</level1>

D:\tmp>type out.xml
<level1>
  <level2>
    <level3 attrname="attrvalue" />
    <coolstuff name="name" />
  </level2>
</level1>
```

As you notice, the `XPath` expression identifies the location for the insertion. [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) is a rich language so you can fine tune it further if you need.

Comment: @Vikharm thanks for your quick response. but it seems that there is a error Object reference not set to an instance of an object for your code

Comment: @JiangJiali This code is to demonstrate how to fix your problem. Do you have a sample file called `file.xml` with the content as I have shown from the command `type file.xml`? In your updated code you have used `fileOfReportInXML` as the variable containing the file name